# Rails 6 nested attributes not deleting existing records when updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm building an application where I have used nested attributes to store different option records under a question record. There is a form where the user can dynamically add and remove options. Everything works fine in my create action, but in the update action, if I remove an existing option and submit the form, it is not deleted from the database.

When updating the question record, is there any way to completely overwrite the existing nested parameters and replace it with the ones we pass in the update request?

I understand that adding `_destroy` to the attributes and passing it as a parameter would satisfy my requirement here. Since I'm deleting the option information from my frontend state on press of a "remove" button in the UI, I'm not sending it along with the params. Is there any other method in Rails to completely overwrite nested attributes and delete those nested records which are not passed in the update request, from the update action in the controller itself?

question.rb

```rb
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quiz
  has_many :options

  validates :body, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options
end
```

option.rb

```rb
class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question

  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :is_correct, inclusion: { in: [ true, false ], message: "must be true or false" }
end
```

questions_controller.rb

```rb
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
 ...

 def update
   @question = Question.find_by(id: params[:id])
   if @question.update(question_params)
     render status: :ok, json: { notice: t("question.successfully_updated") }
   else
     render status: :unprocessable_entity, json: { error: @question.errors.full_messages.to_sentence }
   end
 end

...

private

  def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:body, :quiz_id, options_attributes: [:id, :body, :is_correct])
  end
```

[Relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859967/rails-delete-nested-attribute-while-updating-entry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're deleting the options one by one by clicking a button next to the option. Thats not actually something you need or want to use nested attributes for. Nested attributes is only relevant when you're creating/editing multiple records at once.

While you can destroy a single nested record by updating the parent:

```
patch '/questions/1', params: { 
  question: { options_attributes: [{ id: 1, _destroy: true }] }
}
```

Its very clunky and not really a good RESTful design.

Instead you can just setup a standard `destroy` action:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :options, only: :destroy
```

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy option', option, method: :delete %>
```

```
class OptionsController < ApplicationController
  # @todo authenticate the user and 
  # authorize that they should be allowed to destroy the option
  # DELETE /options/1
  def destroy
    @option = Option.find(params[:id])
    @option.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @option.question, notice: 'Option destroyed' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end 
end
```

This uses the correct HTTP verb (DELETE instead of PATCH) and clearly conveys what you're doing.

Comment: > Thats not actually something you need or want to use nested attributes for. 

Actually I'm using nested attributes to store multiple options which belongs_to question. So while editing the question, I needed the options deleted from the frontend to reflect in the database. The options only need be deleted when the form is submitted

Comment: The standard way to do that is by just including a `_destroy` checkbox. If you want to make that a link instead you could create an event handler which creates a hidden input. From a UI / UX perspective it doesn't make sense though. Its highly confusing if you have a button where it says "delete this option" and then the user has to submit the entire form.

Comment: Its better to just write a event handler which sends the `DELETE /options/1` request and then removes the inputs when the AJAX call completes.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, I have currently implemented it by adding a `_destroy` key to the options object and only displaying the ones which has `_destroy` set to false.

Comment: Can you explain why it's not RESTful design?

Comment: @YaroslavNychka Because you're sending a PATCH request  and not DELETE and its not actually clear whats actually going on without looking at the parameters burried in the request body. There are cases where nested attributes are appropriate but not always.

Answer (score 0):

I can share my recent project work which is a bit similar to your where I am using shrine gem for upload images and I can update/destroy images which is associated with a Product model
product.rb

```
.
.
has_many :product_images, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images, allow_destroy: true
```

product_image.rb

```
.
  belongs_to :product
.
```

_form.html.erb for update

```
<%= f.hidden_field(:id, value: f.object.id) %>
<%= image_tag f.object.image_url unless f.object.image_url.nil? %>
<%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
```

and in products controller,I have whitelisted this

```
product_images_attributes: [:_destroy,:image, :id]
```

Hope this helps you to solve on your case